# find and update with pull and get the pulled document in return

Tags: mongodb

Here is my collection

```
[
  {_id:1,
    persons:[{name:"Jack",age:12},{name:"Ma",age:13}]
  }

]
```

I want to remove `{name:"Jack",age:12}` in `persons` by pull but I also want after pulling is completed I will be returned the pulled `{name:"Jack",age:12}`. How can I do this?

I want to do it like this

```
db.getCollection('test').findOneAndUpdate({_id:1},{$pull:{"persons":{name:"Jack"}}},
{projection:{"person":{
    $filter : {
        input: "$persons",
        as : "ele",
        cond : {$eq : ["$$ele.name","Jack"]}
        
        }
    }}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$reduce`, because `$filter` will return array, also [aggregation array operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#projection) will support from MongoDB 4.4,

```
db.getCollection('test').findOneAndUpdate({_id:1},
    { $pull: { "persons": { name: "Jack" } } },
    { 
        projection: { 
            "person":{
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$persons",
                    initialValue: {},
                    in: { $cond: [{$eq: ["$$this.name","Jack"]}, "$$this", "$$value"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UiHe8z1YXqY)

Comment: can you show me this in play ground, if works I will mark it as answer ?

Comment: `"errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: person: { $reduce: { input: \"$persons\", initialValue: {}, in: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ \"$$this.name\", \"Jack\" ] }, \"$$this\", \"$$value\" ] } } }"`

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb?  look at this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#projection

Comment: The version is 4.2

Comment: Ok so this will support only in 4.4 version